# Spring Boot and JpaRepository - delete should return list of deleted objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jparepository

Is it possible to return deleted objects? I use Mysql. I want to avoid too many db requests

```
public interface FileRepository extends JpaRepository<File, Long> {
@Modifying
    @Query(value = """
            DELETE * FROM file f 
            WHERE f.id IN :ids
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM time_window_file twf WHERE twf.file_id = f.id)
            """, nativeQuery = true)
    List<File> deleteFilesByIdsIfNotUsed(Set<Long> ids);
```

`time_window_file` has only two columns: `time_window_id` and `file_id`

With this "solution" I get the following error:
[Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets.]

Comment: Not with a native query, if you turn it into the Spring Data JPA version then the behavior you want is supported.

Comment: the question is - how to do that

Comment: try to remove,  `nativeQuery = true`  from `@Query`

Comment: Then I get error: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query as :

```
with tab1 as (
    SELECT * FROM file f 
        WHERE f.id IN :ids
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM time_window_file twf WHERE twf.file_id = f.id)
),
tab2 as (
    DELETE FROM file f 
        WHERE f.id in (select distinct(id) from tab1)
)
SELECT * FROM tab1;
```

*[tested in Postgres]*

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible in MySQL